# Class cast exception when casting an object generated by Relections library

Tags: java, generics, reflection, casting

Basically, what I want is to get all classes that implement an interface. But when I stream the list of objects returned by Reflections.getSubTypesOf, and do a cast, I got:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.lang.Class to com.czetsuya.api.error.ExceptionToErrorCode
```

Here are some parts of the code:

Returns a list of classes that implement an interface from a package:

```
public static Set<Class<?>> getSubclasses(String packageName, Class parentClass) {
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections(packageName);
    return reflections.getSubTypesOf(parentClass);
}
```

Cast the returned list of objects:

```
private Stream<ExceptionToErrorCode> implementations() {
    return ReflectionUtils.getSubclasses("com.weddinghighway.api", ExceptionToErrorCode.class).stream().map(p -> {
        return ExceptionToErrorCode.class.cast(p);
    });
}
```

Performs filtering:

```
public ErrorCode of(Exception exception) {
    return implementations() //
        .filter(impl -> impl.canHandle(exception)) //
        .findFirst() //
        .map(impl -> impl.toErrorCode(exception)) //
        .orElse(ErrorCode.UnknownErrorCode.INSTANCE);
}
```

Note: I'm using a nested class, not sure if it's causing something:

```
public class GenericApiExceptionMappers {

    static class FileDoesNotExistsExceptionToErrorCode implements ExceptionToErrorCode {
        @Override
        public boolean canHandle(Exception exception) {
            return exception instanceof FileDoesNotExistsException;
        }

        @Override
        public ErrorCode toErrorCode(Exception exception) {
            return GenericApiErrorCodes.FILE_DOES_NOT_EXISTS;
        }
    }

    static class InvalidParameterExceptionToErrorCode implements ExceptionToErrorCode {
    }

}
```

Comment: You're casting the *class*, not an *instance* of the class.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. cast method says: "Casts an object to the class or interface represented by this Class object.". That means p is being cast to ExceptionToErrorCode class? Did I missed something? Thanks.

Comment: You're finding all the subclasses. You're never creating any *instances* of the classes. `Class.cast` is a reflection equivalent of language-based casting. For example: `Object x = 10; Integer i = (Integer) x; Integer j = Integer.class.cast(x);` - that's two ways of casting. It's as if you're trying to do: `Number n = Number.class.cast(Integer.class);` and that's not going to work.

Comment: You're trying to cast, for example `Class<String>` to a `String`. You have a reference to the `Class` - i.e. the object the JVM uses to represent the actual loaded `.class` file - and you're trying to cast it to an instance of said class.

Comment: You could probably accomplish this goal better using [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) rather than reflection.

Comment: I see. Yes you're right! I got the class template, but not yet instantiated. I'm thinking they are beans / components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of casting the Class, what I did was instantiate it. Here are the changes to the code:

```
private Stream<ExceptionToErrorCode> implementations() throws Exception {
    return ReflectionUtils.getSubclasses("com.czetsuya.api", ExceptionToErrorCode.class).stream().map(p -> {
        try {
            return ExceptionToErrorCode.class.cast(p.newInstance());
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

Since a null value can be included in the returned list when we instantiate due to exception, we should filter it out.

```
public ErrorCode of(Exception exception) throws Exception {
    return implementations() //
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)//
        .filter(impl -> impl.canHandle(exception)) //
        .findFirst() //
        .map(impl -> impl.toErrorCode(exception)) //
        .orElse(ErrorCode.UnknownErrorCode.INSTANCE);
}
```